# Why does this code stop working at Row 21?

Tags: excel, vba

There are several sheets in the workbook.  when it gets to this one sheet, it works until it gets to row 21 then jumps out to iterate to the next sheets.  Weird.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''Iterate all worksheets to:                    ''''
''''    1) delete column A - size sorter          ''''
''''    2) delete all rows without a quantity     ''''
''''    3) change all rows color to white         ''''
''''    4) sort columns by harm code              ''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim chkcell As String
 Dim lastrow As Long

For Each MmasterWS In MmasterWB.Worksheets   'process each sheet in workbook
    MmasterWS.Range("A:A").Delete    'delete column A - size sorter
    
    lastrow = MmasterWS.Range("B" & MmasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    MmasterWS.Range("A4:O" & lastrow).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'change all rows to no fill
    
     For Each rng In MmasterWS.Range("B3:O" & lastrow)    'iterates data range to find empty rows
        
        If lastrow = 3 Then    'sorts sheet by harm code. iterates to next sheet in workbook
            lastrow = MmasterWS.Range("B" & MmasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If MmasterWS.Name = "Panel Schedules" Then
                MmasterWS.Delete
                GoTo skip2
            End If
            With MmasterWS.Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add2 Key:=MmasterWS.Range("C4:C" & lastrow), Order:=xlAscending 'sort by harm code
                .SetRange MmasterWS.Range("A3:N" & lastrow)
                .Header = xlYes
                .Apply
            End With
            GoTo skip2
        Else
''''''''''''''THIS IS WHERE IT WILL GET TO ROW 21 AND SKIP OUT TO NEXT WS
            chkcell = MmasterWS.Range("A" & lastrow).Value
                If chkcell = "" Or chkcell = "0" Then  'if chkcell value of 0 or blank delete row
                    MmasterWS.Range("A" & lastrow).EntireRow.Delete 
                End If
            lastrow = lastrow - 1  'iterate backwards
        End If
     Next

skip2:
Next
```

It works fine on all the other sheets in the workbook.

Comment: What's the value of `lastrow` when this occurs?

Comment: You have the loop `For Each rng In MmasterWS.Range("B3:O" & lastrow)`, but you never use `rng` inside the loop.

Comment: Value when it occurs is 21.  It should go to 3 then process the top part of the if statement

Comment: `lastrow = lastrow - 1  'iterate backwards`... this doesn't iterate backwards at all. `lastrow = lastrow - 1` doesn't affect your `For Each rng` loop at all. Maybe that's not your intent, but I don't understand what you mean by "go to 3."

Comment: Side note: `GoTo skip2` accomplishes nothing, since all that follows it is the `else` statement that would be ignored anyways if the `if` condition is true

Comment: I cleaned up the code and it work correctly now.  Thank you for all the input.